# Receiving JQuery $.post data and returning specific results with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a dynamic website on a single webpage and I'm almost there. All that's left is to do some php coding.

Here is a few lines of code from my "index.php"

```
$('.open').click(function(){
    current = $(this).html();
    $.post("source.php",  {name: current}, function(src){
        $('#codeBox').html(src);
    }); 
});
```

How do I check the value of "current" in my php file and return data specific to the link I click on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$val = $_POST["name"];
$a = array();    
switch($val) {
    case 'some val':
        $a['something'] = "something else";
        print json_encode($a);
    break;    
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just tested this and it did exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 3):

Simply check the POST parameters :

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

Don't forget to sanitize your inputs.

What's the content of you `.open` element ? Maybe it would be preferable to check the element's id, compare the html make me surprising.

Comment: Its <a class="open" href="#">Test</a>

Comment: It's more accurate to use an identifier : <a class="open" id="test" href="#">, because the day you would write "My Test", you php code will be obsolete. The `id` is a simple solution, you can also use the `data-` attributes : http://api.jquery.com/data/

Ex : <a href="#" data-action="test" class="open">
$(".open").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var action = $(this).data("action");
    ...
});

Answer (score 0):

```
<?PHP

// $_POST['name'], this will give you the value of name in the php file
echo $_POST['name']; // this will output it   

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$current = $_POST["name"];
```

using `$current` you can return the data conditionally.